# Html resize content after width change (Anuglar4) like md-sidenav

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have some content with menu on left side, and I have a button in menu, when i press this button, width of menu became smaller, and i want that in that moment width of my content goes bigger(resize to fit).

This effect is exist in https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples
md-sidenav, when you press the + button, content goes bigger or smaller.

I want this resize on my button :), mb there is some css or javascript/typescript...?

I'm using Angular 4

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably by using the flex layout - the side menu would have a fixed width and the content would have a flexible width.
See this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wiCQnoK5JQB8JM8wuJLL?p=preview). For playing with flex options, you can check this [flex playground](https://demos.scotch.io/visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-flexbox-playground/demos/). To add a simple resize animation, use the [Angular animations guide](https://angular.io/guide/animations) - create two states that animate the `width` property of the side menu.

Answer (score 0):

[@thalesrc/ng-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@thalesrc/ng-utils) has a directive which animates automatically when the size changes

Install: `npm i -S @thalesrc/ng-utils @thalesrc/resize-manager`

```
import { ResizeModule } from '@thalesrc/ng-utils/resize';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ResizeModule
  ],
})
export class YourModule { }
```

then

```
<your-component thaAnimateResize duration="300"></your-component>
```